# calling signalr on method from angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs, signalr

I am making web app with angular and @microsoft/signalr. I am able to read data and log it in the console but when i try to use incoming value in another component. data coming as null.

Here is my signal service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

  private hubConnection: HubConnection;

  public data: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.data = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  }

  public startConnection(): void {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://testServer.com:4301/notify', {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection started succesfully');
        this.registerRealTimeEvents();
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));
  }

  public registerRealTimeEvents(): void {
    this.data = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]); // create the subject

    this.hubConnection.on('ListTenorMessage', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data.next(data);
    });
  }

}
```

here up I can see the incoming data when socket send message.

And here my init method when I call:

```
  this.signalRService.startConnection();
    this.signalRService.data.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

Would someone has any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I see you assign the behavior subject twice. I wonder if that is causing you trouble. Try taking out one of the `this.data = …` and see if it works.

Comment: Where do you call this.signalRService.startConnection() from? Maybe you are calling this more than once. If that is the case then call it either from the root component (AppComponent) or in the constructor of your signalRService.

Comment: Its the same result. Actually when it called from component, in any case response comings as how its defined in the constructer. But when removed from constructor, Its not supporting .subscribe method